# Down-sampling a difference between two series, retaining High and Low prints

Tags: time-series

Let's say I have two very high-frequency time series, that I want to downsample at the time of ingest into a database. The typical way to do this is with an Open/High/Low/Close "candle". So far so good.

But what if at some future stage, I want to know the High or Low print between the *difference* of the two series. Open and Close is easy as their index position is always the same, I just take the difference of the two Opens to get the Open of the difference of the series. But the index positions of the High and Low of each series are different, so I cannot simply subtract one OHLC candle, from the other, to get the High and Low prints of the difference series.

Of course, I could downsample and ingest the differences too, but then I get size explosion because say for 100 series, I have 100x99 differences.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem? That is, to store downsampled data per-series that also gives me accurate High and Low prints of their differences?

Here is an example in R, with two series x1 and x2, where two sample periods of 100 data points each are downsampled to OHLC:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see already optically that the High(x1 - x2) is not the same as High(x1) - High(x2). Similarly for Low. Here it is numerically:

```
ohlc <- function(series) {o <- series[1]; h <- max(series); l <- min(series); c <- rev(series)[1]; c(o, h, l, c)}

> ohlc(x1)
[1] -0.670020 10.692085 -9.049464 -5.235760
> ohlc(x2)
[1]  -0.5987462   2.3097553 -21.6404571 -20.6999062
> ohlc(x1 - x2)
[1] -0.07127379 21.27152458 -1.19531333 15.46414630
> ohlc(x1) - ohlc(x2)
[1] -0.07127379  8.38232928 12.59099351 15.46414630
```

As per the graphical output, you can see that the last two lines are different for high and low.

Is there a way to store the Highs and Lows of the differences between a whole lot of series, efficiently (ie, without storing all of them, just storing downsampled details of their "parent" series)?

**ADDENDUM POST BOUNTY OFFERING**

I am happy to accept answers that give me a statistical idea of the diff highs and lows, as opposed to the exact number. For example is there some kind of descriptive statistic that would summarise the interval with time information that I could use to get "close" to diff highs and lows.

Comment: Do you only have the high and lows or also the time points when these high and lows are occuring?

Comment: Are the series from your R example some standard data set?

Comment: So @SextusEmpiricus I just used `cumsum(rnorm(100))` for the data series. You don't need to set the seed most of the time it just gives you 3 series which are nicely representative of the problem.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc we will want to find maximum gain or loss from trading the difference between the two series. In the end this stuff tends to be brought down to a Value at Risk (VaR) which is basically just the standard deviation.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc The 1:1 is a stylized ratio because it makes zero difference to the problem at hand what the loadings are. x:y for any x, y real numbers, as long as they're of the same order of magnitude, results in exactly the same problem.

Comment: It makes a difference because since you mentioned data storage different loadings will require much more storage than you are even anticipating

Comment: yes that's a good point @CagdasOzgenc which I had not thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Interpolation

> But the index positions of the High and Low of each series are different, so I cannot simply subtract one OHLC candle, from the other, to get the High and Low prints of the difference series.

If we would know the time points of the high and lows then we can estimate the level of the other series by interpolation.

Then use the minimum and maximum value for the differences between te highs and lows and the interpolated values of the other series.

This method requires storing twice the amount of data. The values *and also* the times.

The example below shows that there are still some discrepancies. This is when the high and lows of the differences happen somewhere in between the high and lows of the series. The maximum discrepancy could be computed as 'high of series 1 minus low of series 2' and 'high of series 2 minus low of series 1'.

#### Example

The code below demonstrates this with the index of IBM and NIKE.

The OHLC data are computed for the months based on the average (of opening and closing) for the daily values.

For each month we compare all the differences, the opening, closing and the highs and lows with the interpolated values and then choose the minimum and maximum of these. Below you see an example of month 110. The data are the open dots. The lines is what is used for estimation of the highs and lows of the difference.

[image: example month 110]

The images below show how this interpolation method and comparing all differences (the new method), differs from taking the difference between the highs (the simple method).

[image: highs]

[image: lows]

#### R Code

```r
library(tseries)

### get data
ibm = get.hist.quote(instrument = "IBM", 
                     start = "1991-01-02", end = "2021-10-31")
nike = get.hist.quote(instrument = "NKE", 
                     start = "1991-01-02", end = "2021-10-31")

ibm_m = (as.numeric(ibm[,1]) + as.numeric(ibm[,4]))/2
nike_m = (as.numeric(nike[,1]) + as.numeric(nike[,4]))/2


#plot(ibm[1:100,2], ylim = c(1,40), type = "p")
#lines(nike[1:100,2], col = 2)

### time stuff
t = time(ibm)
t_years = as.numeric(format(t, "%Y"))
t_months = as.numeric(format(t, "%m"))
t_days = as.numeric(format(t, "%d"))
id_month = (t_years-min(t_years))*12+t_months

### extract OHLC
### includes the times of the points
OHLC = function(id_month,t_days,series) {
  open = c()
  high = c()
  low = c()
  close = c()
  dopen = c()
  dhigh = c()
  dlow = c()
  dclose = c()
  for(mm in min(id_month):max(id_month)) {
    sel = which(id_month == mm)
    dh = which.max(series[sel])
    dl = which.min(series[sel])
    
    ### OHLC
    high = c(high,  series[sel][dh])
    low =  c(low,   series[sel][dl])    
    open = c(open,  head(series[sel], n=1))
    close = c(close,tail(series[sel], n=1))
    
    ### times
    dhigh = c(dhigh,  t_days[sel][dh])
    dlow =  c(dlow,   t_days[sel][dl])   
    dopen = c(dopen,  head(t_days[sel], n=1))
    dclose = c(dclose,tail(t_days[sel], n=1))
  }
  
  return(data.frame(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close, 
              dopen = dopen, dhigh = dhigh, dlow = dlow, dclose = dclose))
}

info1 = OHLC(id_month,t_days,ibm_m)
info2 = OHLC(id_month,t_days,nike_m)

info_d = OHLC(id_month,t_days,nike_m-ibm_m)


interpolate = function(v,t,int) {
  if (int %in% t) {
    out = v[which(t==int)]
  } else {
    k = max(which(t<int))
    out = v[k] + (v[k+1]-v[k])*(int-t[k])/(t[k+1]-t[k])
  }
  out
}

### computes OHLC for difference

comp_diffOHLC = function(OHLC1,OHLC2, plotting = 0) {
  ### order data and times
  t1 = as.numeric(OHLC1[5:8])
  t2 = as.numeric(OHLC2[5:8])
  o1 = order(t1)
  o2 = order(t2)
  t1 = t1[o1]
  t2 = t2[o2]
  v1 = as.numeric(OHLC1[o1])
  v2 = as.numeric(OHLC2[o2])
  
  if (plotting == 1) {
    plot(-10,-10, xlim = c(1,31), ylim = c(0,150), 
         xlab = "day in the month",
         ylab = "price level")
    lines(t1,v1)
    lines(t2,v2, col = 2)
    points(t1,v1, pch = 21, col =1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7)
    points(t2[2],interpolate(v1,t1,t2[2]), pch = 21, col =1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7)
    points(t2[3],interpolate(v1,t1,t2[3]), pch = 21, col =1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7)
    points(t2,v2, pch = 21, col =2, bg = 2, cex = 0.7)
    points(t1[2],interpolate(v2,t2,t1[2]), pch = 21, col =2, bg = 2, cex = 0.7)
    points(t1[3],interpolate(v2,t2,t1[3]), pch = 21, col =2, bg = 2, cex = 0.7)
  }
  
  ### dists will contain differences at different time points
  dists = c(v2[1]-v1[1],v2[4]-v1[4]) ### difference opening + closing
  dists = c(dists, v2[2]-interpolate(v1,t1,t2[2]), v2[3]-interpolate(v1,t1,t2[3]))  
  dists = c(dists, interpolate(v2,t2,t1[2])-v1[2], interpolate(v2,t2,t1[2])-v1[2])  
  
  return(list(open = dists[1],high = max(dists), low = min(dists), close = dists[2]))
}

### compute approximate OHLC for differences
l = length(info1[,1])
result = sapply(1:l , FUN = function(x) {
  OHLC1 = info1[x,]  
  OHLC2 = info2[x,] 
  comp_diffOHLC(OHLC1,OHLC2)
  })
opens = as.numeric(result[1,])
highs = as.numeric(result[2,])
lows = as.numeric(result[3,])
closes = as.numeric(result[4,])



plot(info_d$high,type = "l", lwd = 2, ylim = c(-170,70),
     xlab = "month index", ylab = "price level difference", main = "highs nike-ibm")
lines(highs,col = 2)
lines(info2$high-info1$high, col=4, lty = 2)

legend(0,70, c("true highs of difference", "new method" ,"simple method"),
       lwd = c(2,1,1), col = c(1,2,4), lty = c(1,1,2), cex = 0.85)

plot(info_d$low,type = "l", lwd = 2, ylim = c(-170,70),
     xlab = "month index", ylab = "price level difference", main = "lows nike-ibm")
lines(lows,col = 2)
lines(info2$low-info1$low, col=4, lty = 2)

legend(0,70, c("true highs of difference", "new method" ,"simple method"),
       lwd = c(2,1,1), col = c(1,2,4), lty = c(1,1,2), cex = 0.85)


### plot of month 110
n = 110           
OHLC1 = info1[n,]  
OHLC2 = info2[n,]  
plotting = 1
comp_diffOHLC(OHLC1,OHLC2, plotting = 1)
sel = which(id_month == n)
points(t_days[sel], ibm_m[sel])
points(t_days[sel], nike_m[sel], col = 2)
title("example month 110 ibm (black) and nike (red)")
```